# Error when invoking a dataflow flex template from a Python Cloud Function

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to invoke a Dataflow flex template from a Python Cloud Function using the following code:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

dataflow = build('dataflow', 'v1b3')
request = dataflow.projects().templates().launch(
    projectId=projectid,
    gcsPath=template,
    body={
        'jobName': job_name,
        'parameters': parameters,
    }
)
print(f"Start to execute Dataflow Job with name: {job_name}")
return request.execute()
```

This same code works if referencing a classic template, but when referencing a flex template, it errors, with the following details:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker_v2.py", line 449, in run_background_function _function_handler.invoke_user_function(event_object) File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker_v2.py", line 268, in invoke_user_function return call_user_function(request_or_event) File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker_v2.py", line 265, in call_user_function event_context.Context(**request_or_event.context)) File "/user_code/main.py", line 41, in trigger_cleaning response = call_dataflow(project_id, job_name, template, parameters) File "/user_code/utils/gcp_utils.py", line 58, in call_dataflow 'parameters': parameters, File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 134, in positional_wrapper return wrapped(*args, **kwargs) File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 915, in execute raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri) googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://dataflow.googleapis.com/v1b3/projects/concise-flame-279117/templates:launch?gcsPath=gs%3A%2F%2Filan-artefacts%2Ftemplates%2Ftemplate666.json&alt=json returned "(145ec02dfb186de2): There is no support for job type with environment version . Please try upgrading the SDK to the latest version. You can find the instructions on installing the latest SDK at https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/installing-beam-sdk. If that doesn't work, please contact the Cloud Dataflow team for assistance at https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/support.
```

That *"There is no support for job type with environment version . Please try upgrading the SDK to the latest version. You can find the instructions on installing the latest SDK at https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/installing-beam-sdk. If that doesn't work, please contact the Cloud Dataflow team for assistance at [https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/support"](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/support%22)* error doesn't make any sense since this is running within a Cloud function...

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE: SOLVED**

The following code solve the issue:

```
dataflow = build('dataflow', 'v1b3')
request = dataflow.projects().locations().flexTemplates().launch(
    projectId=projectid,
    location=location,
    body={
        'launchParameter': {
            'jobName': job_name,
            'containerSpecGcsPath': template,
            'parameters': parameters
        }
    }
)
print(f"Start to execute Dataflow Job with name: {job_name}")
return request.execute()
```

Comment: The created dataflow template has the latest apache-beam[gcp] version (2.24.0). The same error happens if running this from a local python script with the appropriate Service account.

Comment: I'm getting the same error, probably need to file a case with Google.

Comment: For the purpose of traceability, please post your update with the solution as an answer and accept it. This way you will better help future members having the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

Hmm, looks like there is a separate endpoint/call for running flex templates: [docs](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/projects.locations.flexTemplates/launch). This worked for me:

```py
dataflow = build('dataflow', 'v1b3', cache_discovery=False)
request = dataflow.projects().locations().flexTemplates().launch(
    projectId='my-project',
    location='us-central1',
    body={
      'launch_parameter': {
        'jobName': 'testing-1234',
        'parameters': {
          'some_parameter': 'hello',
        },
        'containerSpecGcsPath': 'gs://my-storage-bucket/flex_templates/do_something.json'
      }
    }
)
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code solve the issue:

```
dataflow = build('dataflow', 'v1b3')
request = dataflow.projects().locations().flexTemplates().launch(
    projectId=projectid,
    location=location,
    body={
        'launchParameter': {
            'jobName': job_name,
            'containerSpecGcsPath': template,
            'parameters': parameters
        }
    }
)
print(f"Start to execute Dataflow Job with name: {job_name}")
return request.execute()
```